# How to use shared memory in android native code?

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-memory

I am porting an existing linux application to android. The application is using shared memory API's like `shm_open()` etc.

Checking [bionic in android source](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/search?q=&defs=shm_open&refs=&path=&hist=&project=bionic), I see that these API's are not supported. Hence I get a linking error during build.

```
external/l2/avbtp.c:138: error: undefined reference to 'shm_open'
external/l2/avbtp.c:151: error: undefined reference to 'shm_unlink'
external/l2/avbtp.c:186: error: undefined reference to 'shm_unlink'
```

How to resolve this correctly?

Answer (score 5):

[Android intentionally doesn't provide SysV IPC](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/4e159d95ebf23b5f72bb707b0cb1518ef96b3d03/docs/system/libc/SYSV-IPC.TXT). Try to avoid using of shared memory or, if you really want, look for examples of using `ashmem`.