# Is there any c interface to use Android binders

Tags: android, c, android-binder, ashmem

Basically I need to use shared memory. From [this example](http://www.androidenea.com/2010/03/share-memory-using-ashmem-and-binder-in.html), I understood that i need to use binders to pass the fd between 2 processes to be able to use shared memory.

But my application is in C. So, is there a C interface for using android binders?

Comment: cannot you use http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html ?

Comment: No @pskink. Please see this question that i posted yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38633713/how-to-use-shared-memory-in-android-native-code